# Pretty bad screen tearing on non primary monitors in a multi-monitor setup. (Nvidia)

Tags: nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, tearing

My setup right now includes 2x 1080p monitors, 1x 1440p (primary) monitor hooked up to a GTX1070. The driver version is the current default 370.23. I haven't tried up the new ones from Nvidia directly.

Tearing happens almost exclusively on the 1080p monitors (non-primary) under various circumstances but the issue is most noticeable during video playback.

I've tried a couple of things like triple buffering and ForceFullCompositionPipeline as well as other things but they haven't helped at all as far as I can tell.

Things of note are that Sync to VBlank is enabled and Xvideo Settings has the display device synced to the 1440p monitor (primary) on Nvidia Settings. Something else I noticed was that my 1440p monitor has a refresh rate of 59.95Hz while the other two that experience the most tearing by far are at 60Hz.

I'm lost as to where to go to next. Would greatly appreciate any feedback that can lead to a solution.

Comment: This guy claims to have solved screen tearing with Nvidia under Linux: [i-have-finally-found-a-way-to-sort-out-screen-tearing-on-nvidia-with-linux](https://www.gamingonlinux.com/articles/i-have-finally-found-a-way-to-sort-out-screen-tearing-on-nvidia-with-linux.7213)

Comment: That post is about enabling ForceFullCompositionPipeline. As I mentioned in the post I tried a variation of that and it didn't work. Just in case I tried out the method discussed in there and it also doesn't do anything. Actually, the method discussed in there gave me some weird additional issue: The video stuttered when changing the active windows to something else.

Comment: sorry it wasn't any help. I have a hybrid system with Intel HD4000 + Nvidia GeForce GT650M but have never used the Nvidia or Noveau drivers in large part because of problems you and others experience.